# Made for elementary apps in AppCenter

Tags: appcenter

I see you can find this curated apps directory in the web, but where are they or how can I locate them by properly using AppCenter? I can't find them.
Thank you!

Comment: I think I solved it. It was right there: first uncatalogued apps in each category are 'made for elementary'. Then those 'not reviewed by the editors' (everything else) are not. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curated apps are advertised in AppCenter's home page when you open the app and they are listed first in any category listing before non-curated apps, as you seem to have discovered by your comment.